# Rectangle inside another rectangle

Tags: android, xml-drawable

Is it possible to create drawable from xml like on the picture? The first rectangle contains a second rectangle.

If yes, please explain to me how.

[image: drawable]

Comment: what you want to do by putting rectangle inside a rectangle, do you want to perform some action other that showing this...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want simple rectangles you could use a [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with two shapes as content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#a1a1a1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f1f1f1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I've known about layer-list. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how do shadow effect uses drawable shapes?

Comment: Thanks a Lot :) @Luksprog