# Custom page drawable for ViewPager

Tags: android, drawable, android-viewpager

The Android Music app has a nice implementation of the `ViewPager`. When sliding the pages, it has a vertical separator consisting of two white (I think) lines and transparency in between. What should the page drawable look like to get that look?

```
// Here, 10 dip margin and an XML resource called viewpager_margin...
viewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.viewpager_page_margin));
viewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.drawable.viewpager_margin); // XML = ?
```

Comment: Found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540714/rectangle-inside-another-rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above. The suggestion solution works!